# How do you set a default processor affinity for all programs?

Tags: windows-7, default, processor, affinity

My computer is using windows 7 and has 8 processors. Some of the programs I run do not take up much processing space, but they lag when I use a processor intensive program (like heavily modded Minecraft). These processes I do not want lagging and need to run fine regardless of what other programs I have running.

Is it possible to set every program to, when they boot, have their affinity set to all but one or two processors and either have those certain programs default to the one or two processors or set them myself on boot (they tend to run all the time)?

Comment: It sounds like you have [this problem](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/03/21/399688.aspx)in reverse, so just apply the problem to your system and you're all set.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but a better solution is to reduce the priority on the processor-intensive programs.

Comment: yes that does work a little. ty. although if i set them too low, they might start to lag, so it seems like it might not be the best solution. but im not a computer expert so what do i know.

Comment: @AdamGeisweit The difference is, this approach will never waste CPU. Your approach will, since a CPU may sit idle when there's work to be done because it's the "wrong" CPU. You have to choose -- if there's a CPU shortage, what do you want to get priority? Of course if you choose to make some things faster, other things will be slower. TANSTAAFL